# Fragment onAvtivityResolver Bitmap null error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to take a picture from the gallery in the fragment, although it finds the path, I get a null pointer error while setting the bitmap, how can I edit this code

```
@Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == 777 && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                Uri path = data.getData();
                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), path);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/29804106/6847390](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29804106/6847390) is that answer your question?

Comment: no I'm getting the same error

Comment: I'm working in fragment not activity

Comment: `if (bitmap==null) return;`  You could display a Toast() to inform the user too.

Answer (score 0):

To get data from MediaStore. You have to get permission.

If you're targeting API version 28 or lower. You have to set this in your AndroidManifest:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```